# react with template engine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

hello I decided to create a project with ReactJS NodeJS(ExpressJS) and etc.  have not done a project with this collaboration, before I learned to work with React I was using templating engine (Mustache) and my config for that was this

```
app.engine('html', consolidate.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

but the thing that confused me was this code that I saw on [this page](https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3?fbclid=IwAR2Qcl1LjYqW93nWydoFT1dvAgx2dDX_5bh--oxpbteD47VKzNZQN9jQjnk)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

// An api endpoint that returns a short list of items
app.get('/api/getList', (req,res) => {
var list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
res.json(list);
console.log('Sent list of items');
});

// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('App is listening on port ' + port);
```

They are not using any templating engine but then how can they get rendered variable from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to send all of your variables, or even any of them, with your view. In a RESTful application, the client will be tasked with querying the information to display it later.

In the server code, you will have two 'categories' of routes. The first ones will be just to serve the HTML pages, the second ones will be used to GET and alter content from the server.

Routes to serve the html pages:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('views/index.html'));
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('views/login.html'));
});
```

Routes to get and alter variables from the server:

```
app.get('/api/variable1', function(req, res){
    var variable1 = getFromDatabase('variable1'); //get variable from database
    res.send(variable1); //send variable to front-end
});

app.post('/api/modifyVariable1', function(req, res){
    var newValue = req.body.variable1;
    modifyVariableInDatabase('variable1', newValue); //modify value in database
    res.send({success: true}); //send acknowledgement to client
});
```

In your react front-end, you will be querying the variables and updating your states accordingly to update the view.

```
getVariable1(){
    fetch("/api/variable1")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      }).then((json) => {
        this.setState({variable1: json}); //update 'variable1' in our state
      }).catch((err) => {console.log(err);});
}
```

If you wanted to send the variable with the view directly, instead you will get it as soon as possible in React: in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.getVariable1();
}
```

I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: as i know react only creates SP applications and how will i able to use index and login html same time

Comment: and also what if i want for example greeting message like 'Hello USERNAME' how can i get that username without rendering

Comment: You can have a React script for each page. On index.html, you will use 'index-script.js', and on login.html 'login-script.js'. You will have to use rendering, you will be writing `Hello {this.state.username}` and will query `username` from your server using one of the routes of the second category.

Comment: in that case  should i use componentWillMount i think , am i right

Comment: Doing an async operation (such as a request to the server) in `componentWillMount` will be a problem. Instead, you will want to display either placeholder data, or nothing, until the `this.state.username` value is set.

Comment: so you are telling me i should render component for login.html and in that component when i want to provide user a greeting message i should render and then after rendering with componentDidMount lifecycle method i should fetch data from server?

Comment: i am sorry if i dont understand something properly i have not worked with MERN before as i admitted

Comment: Yes, on component mount and first render you will have the original data in `this.state.username`, which will be either an empty string or some placeholder data (as you want). Then, `componentDidMount()` will trigger and you will query the actual username from the server and use `this.setState` to update the variable and thus the view.

Comment: You can choose to not display anything before querying the username by using short-circuit operators. By writing `{this.state.username != '' && <h4>Hello {this.state.username}</h4>}`, the tag will effectively display only once username is different from an empty string.

Comment: There are some more concepts to grasp, but the base part of a REST application with React is here. All that's left is to actually try all of those and see how the view gets rendered, etc.

Comment: i understood, only thing i did not is technique that u said to use with multiple html pages. also why should i send html files and not use smthing like this 

`       <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/list' component={List}/>
        </Switch> 
`

Comment: Because you did not mention using `react-router` in your original post, so I showcased the traditional way of getting/serving views. You can do it this way instead if you prefer coding the react-router way.

Comment: last quest. is using react-router better than this way?

Comment: React-router is centered on components and mainly used for single-page applications. A benefit of it is that you don't need to load additional views and the user won't see flickering/loading when clicking on another view (login, etc.). You will most likely find a fair share of information on why to use react-router on Google if you're doubting its use.

Answer (score -2):

@jake You can refer Jhipster generator(https://www.jhipster.tech/)
It helps to generate React JS application with basic templates.